# C# is saying that I'm declaring variables when I don't intend to

Tags: c#, string, variables

Given the following code:

```
string a = "example";
string b = "blah {0}", a;
```

I was led to believe that using `{0}` or `{1}`, that it would put whatever is after the comma, in this case string `a`, so `"example"`.  String `b` should be `"blah example"`.  When I do this I get the error "string a is already declared".

Why does it think that I'm declaring a string in this context?

Comment: You need to use the `String.Format` function. Alas, C# has no language syntax for string interpolation, cf. Ruby `"There are #{apples.count} fruit"` or Python `"There are %s fruit" % apples.count"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
string b = "blah {0}", a;
```

declares `string b` with an initial value, and then declares `string a`.

When you specify multiple variable names separated by a comma, it declares them all, e.g.:

```
string a, b, c, d;
```

You probably meant to use String.Format().

```
string b = String.Format("blah {0}", a);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer oO didn't even know about "String.Format" thing

Answer (score 9):

I believe you are intending to use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).  It's not implied (but it would be nice).

```
string b = string.Format("blah {0}", a);
```

Your code would translate like below.  The compiler error is obvious when you expand it out fully.

```
// Given
string a = "example";
string b = "blah {0}", a;

// corresponds to ...
string a; a = "example";
string b; b = "blah {0}";
string a;
```

[MSDN Local variable declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

looks like you're trying to use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

```
string b = String.Format("blah {0}", a);
```

Think of it as a method that builds your string for you.  kinda like `printf` from c/c++

Answer (score 2):

You are re-declaring `a`.

In `c#` and many other languages, it's short hand to declare variables using a comma delimeter.

Example:

```
int x,y,z; // declare three integer variables x y and z
```

You need to use `String.Format`

```
string a = "example";        
string b = string.Format("blah {0}", a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just redeclaring the variable as Eric. J said. Looks like you are trying to connect two strings, so you can use Format function from string class:

```
string a = "example";
string b = string.Format("blah {0}", a);
```

or you can use an operator +:

```
string a = "example";
string b = "blah " + a;
```

Good luck ;).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
string b = string.Format("blah {0}", a);
```

Answer (score 1):

`string b = string.Format("blah {0}", a);`